# Running Flask app in debug mode does not provide the IP or the Debugger PIN or any Request details

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a Flask app, and at first the debug mode was working as expected. It typically had an output such as "Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)" and the Request Status Codes everytime I made any changes and also provided a debugger PIN. 
After making a few changes and re-organizing my App file structure by adding Blueprints, these details do not come up in the command line while running the App.

The output is always just this

```
Serving Flask app "web_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
```

Instead of the previous output, that contained the IP, Debugger PIN etc.

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 139-055-956
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

I can't figure out why this is happening.The changes I made were adding Blueprints and moving a few routes into them, and the initialization of the App was made through an function.

The name of the app is "web_app"

My run.py

```
from web_app import create_app
app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

web_app.**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from web_app.config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_mail import Mail


db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login = LoginManager()
mail = Mail()

def create_app(config_class = Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    from web_app.models import User, Retailer, Results, Watchlist
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    from web_app.main.routes import main
    from web_app.posts.routes import post
    from web_app.user.routes import user
    from web_app.errors.handlers import errors
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(post)
    app.register_blueprint(user)
    app.register_blueprint(errors)
    login.login_view = 'user.login'
    return app
```

config.py

```
import os

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = '5ab34f90107c5d025461e91c2d6ce13d'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///test1.db'
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

I don't know if I have provided enough info for this, please let me know if anything is required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. What exactly is the problem? The environment? How are you running your app?

Comment: Hi, I have edited the Post to better explain this issue. Contained multiple lines and could not use comments for that.The problem is with the Flask App output in the command line while running the app, initially it contains ALL the details such as the Debugger PIN, "Running on https://...localhost... " and if any links were opened, it provided the HTTP Request Status Codes for each request. BUT after I moved the App Initialization into a Procedure called "create_app", the debugger is not working properly. It no longer provides all the above mentioned data.

Comment: Is this problem solved? I am facing this problem now

Answer (score 0):

figured out what the issue was. One of my programs associated with this was using the built-in logging module and all the data was being logged to the log file. Once I removed the log file, and changed the logging config, it started working correctly.
:)

Comment: could you tell me where to find it?